# How can handle html class name in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to find "drop" class name in javascript. I get the formatted as

```
[
<input id="che" type='test' class='drop' role='check'></input>
<span class='icon'></span>]
```

i have used below code snippet but it return undefined element.

```
$('#che').find('.drop')
```

Comment: What's your starting point? Why are you starting with `$("#che")`? Simply `$(".drop")` would do it (for your updated question).

Comment: i get the array element so i cant use the find method directly.

Comment: $("#che") and $(".drop") and $("#che.drop") - same element <input>
$().find used for children element. input not have children element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code isn't doing what you think:

```
$('#che').find('.drop')
```

When you run `$('#che')` it will return a collection containing the `input` class.  running `.find()` on that will then look for elements *within* the found elements, it won't filter that list of elements themselves.  In this case, the use of `.find()` is unnecessary.  `$('#che')` already identifies the `input` in the markup.

If your markup looked like *this*:

```
<div id="che">
    <div class="drop" />
</div>
```

*That* would be identified using the `.find()` off of the first selection.

Comment: *"In this case, the use of .find() is unnecessary..."* And useless, `input` elements cannot have child elements, by definition.

Answer (score -2):

This variant should work `$(".inpch")`